# WCF REST : returning classes and rules / Pascal/Camel case for fields?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, rest, wcf-rest

Can anyone tell me the recomemended case (pascal or camel) for returning classes with fields... For example, the example that comes with vs 2010 uses Pascal Case like so

```
// TODO: Edit the SampleItem class
public class SampleItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

Notice first capital letter on Id and StringValue. I was wondering is this the recommended way? A lot of public services seem to return camelCase as fields.

I must admit it feels more natural with Pascal Case which follows the microsoft naming conventions for Properties etc.

Also the properties are going to be singular because its for 1 record i.e. Id, StringValue etc..  but what about the class name, i presume this will be singular name also as the XML that i return will make an array of SampleItem ??

I am just sort of looking for a bit of confirmation really.

The class i return will contain fields for my specific returned data, is there any fields i should be including by default.... I think not??  As if it fails i just return Error 400 so i don't need to supply any Error Number, Error Desc etc in each class

Any comments really appreciated

EDIT

here is an exmaple of the method i am using to return the xml ... its the default method in the standard vs 2010 template

```
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
    public List<SampleItem> GetCollection()
    {
        // TODO: Replace the current implementation to return a collection of SampleItem instances
        return new List<SampleItem>() { new SampleItem() { Id = 1, StringValue = "Hello" } };
    }
```

Of course this method returns a LIST (only an exmaple) of SampleItem..

SampleItem is a class  and here it is

```
// TODO: Edit the SampleItem class
public class SampleItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are you using to generate the XML?

Comment: I am using the standard template in vs 2010 to return the XML. I update my question with the example item

Comment: Ok question updated, but basically it returns a .NET class which of course is PascalCase :-)

Answer (score 0):

The [Microsoft Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) suggest PascalCasing for properties, and camelCasing for parameters. Therefore, your current casing is correct, if your goal is to match Microsoft's standards.

Comment: Yes, i know my standards are correct for properties and class names etc i just wasn't sure if i need to change these to match an XML output of camel casing... or it doesn't matter....

Comment: Well, like I said, if your goal is to make the XML output match Microsoft's names, then what you're currently doing (what's in the sample) is perfect. If you're defining the XML format, you get to say what it looks like.